# Can't add onclick event to DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm creating a p element inside a div (lets call it "test-div") and i want to add onclick events on it, i can give it a class and an id but I'm getting errors when adding an onclick. It says it has type void. My code is basically this:

```
var son = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("test");
son.appendChild(node);
var father = document.getElementById("test-div");
father.appendChild(son);
son.className = "son-class";
son.id="son-id";
son.onclick= sonFunction(randomVar); //Type 'void' is not assignable error
```

Answer: son.addEventListener("click", function(){sonFunction(randomVar)});

Comment: Use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to change the `onclick` attribute, which is expecting a string, and assigning it the return value of your `sonFunction` which has no return value, hence (`void`).

You can set the `onclick` attribute with a string such as:

```
son.onclick = 'sonFunction(randomVar);';
```

Doing so will give you HTML output similar to:

```
<p class="son-class" onclick="sonFunction(randomVar);">
    ...
</p>
```

However, you probably want to assign it an event listener, which will fire the event when clicked.  Doing the below will not add an `onclick` attribute to the HTML, but keep the listener in the Javascript compiler.  Doing this is often called "unobtrusive" Javascript since the Javascript code is not embedded in the HTML.

```
function sonFunction() {
    // something here
};
son.addEventListener('click', sonFunction);
```

Or

```
son.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // something here
});
```

Comment: son.onclick = 'sonFunction(randomVar);'; it's wrong, its actually what i tried on the first time, i searched on stackoverflow and you actually don't put it in a string.
when doing son.addEventListener('click', sonFunction(randomVar)); i also get error and same for son.addEventListener('click', function (randomVar) {});

Comment: The syntax for addEventListener is incorrect. I was having the same issue and solved with: `img.addEventListener('click', () => this.clickedFunction());`